# Does JetBrains' Material Theme UI send telemetry?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, telemetry

The [popular plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) relatively recently changed from a free plugin to a paid/freemium model. I wanted to know if it collects user data/send telemetry?

[Material UI changed to closed-source](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains) but I don't see any mention of telemetry/data collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://material-theme.com/docs/configuration/settings/#frequently-asked-questions:

> What is that analytics option? What data are collected?

> This is an option to allow sending data to Material Theme servers about users’ configuration, usage and trends. These analytics will allow us to see which features are most used or least used, in order to prioritize development of features, or maybe notify users about specific features, to provide a better satisfaction. These data are completely anonymous, and are not shared/sold to any third parties. If you want to stop sending data, simply turn off the option in the material_theme.xml.

Long-story short: it collects telemetry and you can disable it during the first run after installing plugin in Event Log (*View | Tool Windows | Event Log*):

- Share Anonymous Statistics
- Don't Share

[image]